# Setting up a python pipeline - python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best way to accomplish the following pipeline in python using subprocess:

1. run three script files python1_a.py, python1_b.py, python1_c.py in parallel
2. If no errors have been raised, run python2.py
3. If no errors have been raised, run python3.py

Also I'd want to pass arguments through argprase.

Note: there are print statements in those files to expose progress - what is the best way to log them ?

If you can answer with an example code would be great

Comment: Why don't you use subprocess and check return code?

Comment: Ok can you answer with the exact code using subprocess to make this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

To run in parallel:

```
import subprocess

proc = []
for script in (['python1_a.py', 'arg1'], ['python1_b.py', 'arg2'], ['python1_c.py', 'argx']):
    p = subprocess.Popen(script)
    proc.append(p)

for p in proc:
    p.wait()
```

And later simply:

```
ret = subprocess.call('python2.py arg1 arg2', shell=True)
if not ret:
    subprocess.call('python3.py arg1 arg2', shell=True)
```